# Installing a framework without maven or gradle

Tags: java, api, kotlin, java-8, frameworks

I try to install Javalin framework for creating an API on my Java project. (old java 8 project without maven, gradle, etc). I would like to install the framework with adding the jars to my build path.
But If I add the main jar file then it needs another dependencies jar , then another one another one another one.. etc.

Is there any simple way to add this to my project and all it's dependencies without any build tool like Maven,etc?

I have tried adding it manually , but each jar has many dependencies that it is almost impossible(?)

Comment: Repeatability and dependency handling are the most important reasons for using gradle or maven. Or any other build automation tool for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could create a Maven project and use it to download the dependencies for you.

[Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) might be useful. With it you could just call:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

and it will download all your dependencies into `target/dependency`.

Comment: But the question specifically said “without any build tool like Maven”.

Comment: @gidds Depends how he means without Maven. I suppose he just can't / doesn't want to add Maven to his old project. I am suggesting creation of a new empty Maven project for the sole purpose of downloading the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way, I'm afraid.  Dependency management is the exact problem that build tools like Maven and Gradle were created to solve!

The framework supplier *could* provide a ‘fat’ jar including all the dependencies; but I'm not aware of any that do, as everyone uses Maven or Gradle (or SBT or Ivy or Grape or Leiningen or Buildr).

I think the only real alternative is to do it manually — which, as you've discovered, can be a horrible and lengthy task if the dependency tree is big.  (And would need redoing with every update.)

So I'd suggest biting the bullet and using Maven if you can.